# Thread em estado wait eterno, não acorda com o notify

Tags: java, thread

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema em um projeto envolvendo Threads, estou começando a mexer com Threads agora em um trabalho da faculdade e estou com duvidas a respeito da Thread estar entrando no estado de "WAINTING" mas não acordar nem mesmo com a chamada de um "notifyAll", gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado e a solução. Código:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            if(estado == Estados.FAMINTO)
            {
                if(pegarGarfos())
                {
                    estado = Estados.COMENDO;
                }
            }
            else if(estado == Estados.PENSANDO) 
            {
                Random gerador = new Random();
                int aleatorio = gerador.nextInt()%2;
                if(aleatorio == 0)
                {
                    estado = Estados.FAMINTO;
                }
            }
            else if(estado == Estados.COMENDO)
            {
                soltarGarfos();
                estado = Estados.PENSANDO;
            }
        }

    }catch(InterruptedException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

public synchronized boolean pegarGarfos()
{
    if(!deadlock)
    {
        return garfoDireito.pegarGarfo() && garfoEsquerdo.pegarGarfo();
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if(garfoDireito.pegarGarfo())
            {
                if(garfoEsquerdo.pegarGarfo())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    garfoDireito.soltarGarfo();
                    this.wait();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.wait();
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public synchronized void soltarGarfos()
{
    garfoDireito.soltarGarfo();
    garfoEsquerdo.soltarGarfo();
    this.notifyAll();
}
```

Quando a Thread não consegue acessar os recursos necessários (garfos), ela entra em wait, e quando outra Thread "solta" os garfos ela chama o notifyAll para acordar as Threads que estavam concorrendo pelo garfo e entraram em Wait, ja printei no terminal varias vezes o estado e sempre que uma das Threads entra em Wait ela não sai nunca mais. Agradeço a ajuda e a atenção desde já.